# capturar input typo file y a la hora de editar no se cambie el nombre

Tags: php

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Documento</label>
<input type="file" name="extra2" class="form-control" id="file" value="<?php echo $extra2; ?>" >
</div>
</div>
```

como se puede observar el value no captura el archivo en pdf que este caso se llama extra2 , a la hora de editar obviamente sale en blanco,este es mi controlador:

```
$nombre_extra2="Inventario-img-".date('Y-m-d-h-i-s');
$filename=$nombre_extra2."_".$_FILES['extra2']['name'];

$location="img/".$filename;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['extra2']['tmp_name'],$location);
```

ahora como hacer que capture el input file ya subido y no me pida volver a subirlo , porque al editar sale en blanco

Comment: el atributo `value` del tipo `file` espera un `DOMString`, es decir, una cadena de texto en UTF16 que apunta al archivo con toda su ruta dentro del pc del visitante. Aquí un poco de más info (en ingleś): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: osea a la hora de insertar sii llena la base dde datos la cuestion es a la hora que se da en el boton editar el documento subido ya no carga , como se haria para el documento no lo tengo q volver adjuntar , si no que se queda en la vista o lo muestre.

Comment: No se entiende eso de "Editar" que dices... ¿que quieres editar? ¿de que tipo de archivos estamos hablando? ¿lo quieres editar online?